# Why does range-v3 put its function objects into an inline namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, range-v3, inline-namespaces

In range-v3, all of the functions are really global function objects in an [inline namespace](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/f8c7a4fa298111096b7da83043e6583fa82086be/include/range/v3/detail/config.hpp#L412-L428):

> ```
> #if RANGES_CXX_INLINE_VARIABLES < RANGES_CXX_INLINE_VARIABLES_17
> #define RANGES_INLINE_VARIABLE(type, name)                              \
>     inline namespace function_objects                                   \
>     {                                                                   \
>         inline namespace                                                \
>         {                                                               \
>             constexpr auto &name = ::ranges::static_const<type>::value; \
>         }                                                               \
>     }
>
> #else  // RANGES_CXX_INLINE_VARIABLES >= RANGES_CXX_INLINE_VARIABLES_17
> #define RANGES_INLINE_VARIABLE(type, name) \
>     inline namespace function_objects      \
>     {                                      \
>         inline constexpr type name{};      \
>     }
> #endif // RANGES_CXX_INLINE_VARIABLES
> ```

What is the purpose of the `function_objects` namespace? It is not referenced anywhere else in the library as far as I can tell.

Comment: Probably has to do something with linkage, just like libc++'s `std::__1` namespace.

Comment: [This is the PR](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/pull/423) that added this code. Maybe the [comments that CaseyCarter made](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/pull/423#issuecomment-230644140) can shed some light on this

Answer (score 12):

Based on Casey's comments on the [PR](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/pull/423) that led to this addition (thanks Justin), the `inline namespace` is necessary for something like this to work:

```
namespace N {
    namespace detail {
        // default implementation
        template <typename T> void swap(T&, T& ) { ... }

        struct swap_fn {
            template <typename T>
            void operator()(T& a, T& b) {
                swap(a, b); // unqualified call, the default is in scope
            }
        };
    }

    // the object
    inline namespace CPO { inline constexpr detail::swap_fn swap{}; } // #1

    struct S { friend void swap(S&, S&) { ... } }; // #2
}

N::S a;
N::swap(a, a); // calls the CPO, which calls the friend function
```

If the customization point object `swap` (at `#1`) were not in its own namespace, there would be a name clash between the cpo and the non-member `friend` declared for type `S` (at `#2`). Those must be in different namespaces.

Putting the CPO in an inline namespace is sufficient because regular unqualified or qualified lookup will never find the swap at `#2` - it will only be found by ADL, which only happens within `swap_fn::operator()`.

Yeah, this is pretty cool. And complex.

Comment: There's some discussion [on the Core reflector](http://lists.isocpp.org/core/2018/04/4164.php) from when I asked if this was legit after convincing myself we were breaking [\[basic.scope.declarative\]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.declarative#4). (TLDR: the inline namespace makes it legit.)